# Как получить элемент на котором сработала кастомная функция?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть метод который срабатывает после загрузки страницы. В этом методе есть строка:

```
$jq('#myElement').myCustomFunction("some info", "sometext");
```

Моя функция принимает 2 параметра:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    myCustomFunction: function (info, text) {

    }
});
```

Есть ли возможность получить айди элемента (`#myElemen`) внутри функции?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для достижения поставленной цели использую `this.prop('id')`:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    myCustomFunction: function (info, text) {
        console.log(this.prop('id'));
    }
});
```

Comment: Да, все нормально. `this` в данном случае объект jQuery. Прошу прощения.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте объект this.

В собственных функциях jQuery this представляет ссылку на элемент dom, на который "навешана" ваша функция, поэтому в вашем случае this ссылается на элемент c ID myElement. Если вы собираетесь применять функцию не только к элементам по ID но и по другим селекторам (вариант что вернется несколько объектов dom) есть смысл использовать конструкцию перебора:

```
$(this).each(function(){
  ...
})
```

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]